# HTML is it possible to set second class inherit the main id?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible for me to set the second class to inherit the main class ID?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/EXardz

```css
.productholder {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#content2p {
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 6cm;
  width: auto;
}

.bookingFormHeader {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
  border: 25px solid green;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content2p">

  <img class="productholder" src="http://via.placeholder.com/662x442.png">
  <p class="bookingFormHeader">Test Test</p>

</div>
```

Explanation :-

I've set a container with the id `content2p` . Here i want to put two class side by side. The first class `productholder` is working fine. My only issue would be `bookingFormHeader` . It's indenting to the bottom, i want to make it same line as below example output:

[image]

The booking is actually a form with border box :

[image]

I've tried many ways by changing the display to the following :-

`inline-block
 flex
 table
 inline-table`

Yet i've got no luck , is there any element I'm missing??
Appreciate in advance.

Comment: no luck, i'm still trying thou but it's based on the display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after? Please adjust margins and width to you liking.

```css
#content2p {
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.bookingFormHeader {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100px;
  border: 25px solid green;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content2p">

  <img class="productholder" src="http://www.placehold.it/80">
  <p class="bookingFormHeader">Test Test</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm looking for.
These are new to me, 
  `justify-content: space-around;`

i'll search the document for it, thank you for an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Have a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: A quick question, cause now for the `bookingformheader` when i tried to put spacing by changing margin , it doesn't gives space

Comment: ignore my comment, its because of the form not being closed.

Answer (score 0):

You also use class inside id

```
<style>
#id
{
****some style
}
.class
{
**codes
}
```

html like this

```
<div id="id>
<div class="class"
</div>
</div>
```